# Python Beautiful Soup Scrape Text in Span Class

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape text in span class and I only want to store the text information I need.

Please see the HTML example below:

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2">
      <span id="plcMain_lblBandNumber" class="control-label" style="font-weight: bold;">Number</span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <span id="plcMain_txtBandNumber" class="control-label">626</span>
   </div>
</div>
<br />
```

The only text I need from the above HTML is 626.

Below is my python code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "Link"
Page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

results = soup.find(id = 'plcMain_textBandNumber')

print(results)
```

The result I got from the print statement is the HTML text below:

[image]

But I only want it to return the value of 626.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Try results.text in the print. Or results.getAttribute('InnerHTML').

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get text you should add to end `text`

```
results = soup.find(id = 'plcMain_textBandNumber').text
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch text like this

```
results = soup.find(id = 'plcMain_textBandNumber').getText()
```